# Could'nt load main class ; SOAPUI Installation Error

Tags: soapui

while installing soapUI im getting an error like "could'nt load main class, c:\windows\temo\i4j_nLog_18"

what is this error? and how can i fix this?

Comment: Is it while installing? or while running soapui?

Comment: May be the installer you downloaded might have been corrupted, please try re-download and install and see.

Comment: The file is not corrupted, its working fine in other systems, i have tried installing the previous version also, i'm getting the same error.

Comment: So, was the earlier question to know if the problem is while invoking the tool. Then what is the change made in your machine compare to other system where it is working?

Comment: @Rao that is actually what i want to know, see i got 2 laptops, both are windows 7, the software is works only in one lap. i need to know whether there is any OS config related to this installation

Comment: You better know about your machine and what you did, isn't it?Why don't you retry installing it?

Comment: same issue exists 5 years later - w/ no useful explanation or workaround

Comment: was forced to drop back to 5.2 "standalone" zip

Answer (score -1):

Run the setup file as administrator.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer